# How to Select/Highligt a Image using jquery on a Specific Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select/highlight a Image by clicking a Button. my purpose is to copy a image.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnCopy").click(function () {



            document.execCommand('copy');
            //Unselect the content
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            //Make the container Div uneditable again
            $(this).removeAttr("contenteditable");
            //Success!!
            alert("image copied!");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi. Can you provide some html code also

Comment: Provide your html code only then expects may help you @Rayhan

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet adapted from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/987376/7252292

```js
function SelectText(element) {
    var doc = document
        , text = doc.getElementById(element)
        , range, selection
    ;    
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        selection = window.getSelection();        
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}

document.onclick = function(e) {    
    if (e.target.className === 'click') {
        SelectText('selectme');
    }
};
```

```html
<div id="selectme"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="click"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### You may use JQuery Clone method

**Note :- The .clone() method performs a deep copy of the set of matched elements, meaning that it copies the matched elements as well as all of their descendant elements and text nodes.**

```js
(function(){
 $('#btnCopy').click(function() {
   var img = $("#firstDiv").children("img").clone();
   alert('image copied');
   $('#pasteImg').append(img);
 });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstDiv"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" /></div>
<button id="btnCopy">Copy Image</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="pasteImg"></div>
```